# Error(13,61): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here IN PROCEDURE WHEN PASS IN PARAMETER

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSEMP 
(
  EMPNOS IN VARCHAR2 
, ENAMES IN VARCHAR2 
, JOBAS IN VARCHAR2 
, MGRS IN VARCHAR2 
, HIREDATES IN VARCHAR2 
, SALS IN VARCHAR2 
, COMMISSIONS IN VARCHAR2 
, DEPTNOS IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO emp VALUES (EMPNOS,ENAMES,JOBAS,MGRS,HIREDATES,SALS,COMMS,DEPTNOS);
END INSEMP;
```

When I execute the above, I get an error:  `Error(13,67): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here`.

I know when we insert

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES ('DSFD'DSFDFD', ...)
```

we have to use single quotes, but how do I pass the values in via the parameters?

Comment: That error is because you have `comms` instead of `commission` in the values list. ([Quick demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ff38cb2f4c83bad57a901dc0e29c04c)). But you should list the target columns as part of the insert statement, and don't have variable/argument names that are the same as column names - it's common to add a prefix like `p_` - to avoid confusion. Also, please don't write everything in uppercase, it's harder to read and makes it seem like you're shouting.

Comment: i change it later  so in copy pasting it come  
but still same error

Comment: ohh after reopening  sql developer it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have a parameter called `COMMISSIONS` but in your insert statement, you are passing in a value of `COMMS`.

Also, make sure your parameters have different names to the columns you're trying to insert into; this is (IMO) good practice across any PL/SQL code you're writing, as you can have unexpected results when name collisions happen.

Change your insert statement to use the right parameter name (or, alternatively, change the name of the parameter to match your insert statement) and it should start working.

One point, though: it is bad practice to not list the columns you are inserting into. In real production code, if someone added a column to the table, your code would break.

Your insert statement would be better written as:

```
insert into <table> (<list of columns to be inserted into>)
values (<list of values to insert into those columns>);
```